# AWS DynamoDB IAM Policy - DENY Query Specific Attributes

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I'm having trouble getting this to work. I setup a policy to first allow a query so the lambda can access my table, but I need it to prevent query on a few specific attributes. I can make it work using an allow with StringNotEquals but I would prefer a DENY so if someone were to add another condition to the policy later they dont accidentally grant access to the restricted attributes. Here's my two Policy Statements:

```
const psAllow = new PolicyStatement({
  resources: [tableArn],
  actions: ['dynamodb:GetItem','dynamodb:BatchGetItem','dynamodb:Query','dynamodb:Scan'],
  effect: Effect.ALLOW
});

const psDeny = new PolicyStatement({
  resources: [tableArn],
  actions: ['dynamodb:GetItem','dynamodb:BatchGetItem','dynamodb:Query', 'dynamodb:Scan'],
  effect: Effect.DENY
});
psDeny.addCondition('StringEquals', {'dynamodb:Select':'SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES'});
psDeny.addCondition('ForAllValues:StringEquals', {'dynamodb:Attributes':['restricted_field1','restricted_field2']});
```

If I omit the conditions the DENY will override the ALLOW and correctly prevent the dynamodb query. As soon as I add a condition the DENY is totally ignored. I must be formatting the condition wrong or just missing something here. Any ideas?

Comment: not sure if this will be of any help ,but if your table doesn't have many attributes , perhaps add the conditions into the allow statement with attributes you want to allow ? instead of the explicit deny

Comment: That's a great idea Darren, but there's reasons I can't use an allow list instead of deny. I know principle of least privilege says to do an allow list, but it's not an option this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ForAnyValues` (instead of `ForAllValues`) in the deny statement.

Comment: when I add: 

psDeny.addCondition('ForAnyValues:StringEquals', {'dynamodb:Attributes':['restricted_field1','restricted_field2']});

I'm getting MalformedPolicyDocument when I switch it